# Stripe connect transfers and payouts without verification

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to clarify things associated with Stripe Connect's `paymentIntent` and `transfers` endpoints. The thing is that I do think that I do not understand the flow perfectly and even do not know if I did choose the best solution for my application.

I am using the [separate charges and transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) method and for the account type I did choose [custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts).

What I want to achieve is the following:

1. Get money from user A and send it to user B (user in this context is my platform user not the Stripe Account or Customer). I want to take my cut while I send the money to user B. It leads to a question, if I do need to create both the Stripe Customer and Account. And if the user B who gets the money after transfer is not acting as a company, why would I need to collect industry and other legal information from him/her just to make payout?

What I did:

First of all I do create Stipe Customer and Account for my platform users. Then I:

1. Create PaymentIntent to take money from (Stripe Customer A). Includes the Stripe fees
2. Create Transfer of the PaymentIntent and transfer it to (Stripe Account B).
3. Now I want to create payout of the transferred money. Do I have to trigger the payout endpoint for this case?

The 3 last steps in code:

Create paymentIntent

```
const paymentIntent = {description, amount, currency, customer_id, transfer_group, payment_method, confirmation_method: 'manual', confirm: true};
const response = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(paymentIntent);
```

Create transfer

```
const transfer = { amount, currency, destination: destinationAccount, transfer_group };
const response = await stripe.transfers.create(transfer);
stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(response.client_secret, {payment_method: response.payment_method})
```

Now money is taken from Customer A and transferred to Account B but I have no idea what legal information I need from my platform users to be able to create payouts? All my Stripe accounts/customers did accept the `tos_acceptance` also while adding a new source. None of my platform users are industry nor a company. They are individuals doing their things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow the flow which you mentioned you need to create stripe Connect account for each of your customer B. As you need to do payouts to there bank accounts they need to be completely verified by stripe [this shows legal information required for verification as per country](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information)
Though your end users are individuals you need to completely prove them for authenticity as you are involving them in legal fund transfer and making there sub-merchant accounts.

And you don't have to trigger the payout end point as it is automatically handled by stripe and you can also change it either you want to do payout weekly/daily/monthly etc and also set for custom payouts from dashboard settings.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up for me. That's what I wanted to know.

Comment: But I still do not get it. How my users are supposed to set their industry if they do not act under a company?

Comment: Stripe automatically sets the industry for your connect accounts to 'Software,SaaS' if it is not been provided. You can also set it manually during creation of connect accounts.